# How to resolve "502 bad gateway" error in Magento2 while trying to access the site?

Tags: nginx, magento2

I am a newbie in Magento2. While I try to access the site after the warden env up command, sometimes this error pops up. This error goes away sometimes while refreshing multiple times. Is there a permanent resolution for this?

Comment: You'd need to check your NGINX error logs for the actual reason behind this. If Bad Gateway is caused by too large response headers, you need to [tweak NGINX](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/tuning-proxy_buffer_size-in-nginx).